# Checkbox within Datagrid retaining checked value on postback in VB.NET but not C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hey there, I have a project in VB.NET which is working fine which essentially has a Datagrid that has a TemplateColumn included which is a column of Checkboxes. The code to declare the datagrid is here...

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgDates" OnItemCommand="gridEventHandler" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px"
CellPadding="3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowSorting="True"
OnSortCommand="SortData" OnItemDataBound="gridItemDataBound">
<HeaderStyle Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black"
    BackColor="#D4D0C8"></HeaderStyle>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="strParameterName" SortExpression="strParameterName" HeaderText="Parameter Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="dtParameterValue" SortExpression="dtParameterValue" HeaderText="Parameter Value"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Constant" SortExpression="blnStatic" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbStaticRolling" Checked="False" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

as you can see the Checkbox has Autopostback="true" but there are other things on the page which produce postbacks as well.

My Page_load has this in it, being called on every load of the page, postbacks included...

```
Dim strGUID As String
strGUID = Session("strGUID")
dgDates.DataSource = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(Web.  [Global].CfgKeyConnStringADMIN), "dbo.spRptGetSchedulingDates", strGUID)
dgDates.DataBind()
intNumberOfDates = dgDates.Items().Count
```

as well my code behind has the following code for the gridItemDataBound

```
Protected Sub gridItemDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs)
    'hide the intRptSchedulingDatesID for each row in the checkbox's content style variable
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        CType(e.Item.FindControl("cbStaticRolling"), CheckBox).Style("Content") = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("intRptSchedulingDatesID")
    End If
End Sub
```

everything you see sbove is working perfectly fine...in the sense that when I click one of the checkboxes, the page_load fires, the gridItemDataBound fires on DataBind() and when all is done, the checkbox retains the value that the user clicked the checkbox.

With all this exact same code converted to C#....the events all fire in the same order, but the checkbox selected value always clears...any thoughts??

Comment: Sorry but I assume you must be missing something. For what I know, there's nothing that could cause different behavior by changing the language, since it's not language-specific, but framework-specific. Please check everything again. Maybe you're missing an Update Panel or something...?

Comment: As C# doesn't have `CType`, maybe there's an error in your conversion. Could you post the C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the problem is that you're are binding the grid on every postback (I can't explain the difference between VB and C#). This clears your selections. Why are you doing this?

Comment: well, to be honest I'm not 10)% sure WHY I do it...I wrote the VB version about a year ago or so, and it's binding the grid on every postback as well, but not losing the selections, it's just recently I've had to convert this code to C# for a new application it's going to be part of that I've noticed it's been clearing the selections...one issue is that every load of this page is a postback, even the first one, because it's an ascx control within an ascx control within an page, so it only ever gets loaded on a postback

Comment: @Scott Fortier: Bind the grid ONLY if it isn't postback. if (!Page.IsPostback) dgDates.DataSource .... Just for testing purposes so we can see if this is the problem or not

Comment: it seems like that is the root of the issue...i just F10'd through the code and skipped over the datasource/databind lines on every postback except the first one, and it seems like that's the issue...hmm, i acutally spent hours fighting with this yesterday.....thanks for the obvious but helpful pointer....I'm sure i can come up with some system using viewstate to determine when the first postback is and when all subsequent postbacks are

Answer (score 0):

You bind the grid on every page_load, this causes checkbox to be always the same.

Try to attach a checkedchange event on ItemDataBound and when event fires, store checkbox value on a session variable.

On ItemDataBound, check session variable and if its null, run this code, otherwise read checkbox's value from your session variable

And On Page_Load, if not IsPostBack (page is loading first time), set your session value to null